# Draw svg line on scroll from section

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, line, draw

I have a svg file on my website that drows in scroll, but I would like the animation start from particular section, can you help me please ?

Code JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myline = document.getElementById("myline");
  var length = myline.getTotalLength();
  myline.style.strokeDasharray = length;
  
  myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
  
  window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
  
  function myFunction() {
    var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var draw = length * scrollpercent;
  
    myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
  
    endPoint = myline.getPointAtLength(draw);
  
  }


});
```

Thank you !

Comment: Complete code : https://jsfiddle.net/integraweb/0ju8ykde/1/